# listview 2 condition layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, if-statement

I have problem in condition the layout in one listview. I manage to print messagesArrayList.get(position).getUsersId(); value is "89" but in the if else condition not working, it keep return OTHER. please help me. thanks

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //getting message object of current position 
    m = messagesArrayList.get(position).getUsersId();
    //If its owner  id is  equals to the logged in user id
    if (m == "89") {
        //Returning self
        return SELF;
    }
    else{
        return OTHER;
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Adapter.ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new Adapter.ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(getItemViewType(position) == SELF) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_threat, null, false);
        }
        else if(getItemViewType(position)==OTHER){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_thread_other, null, false);
        }

        holder.tvmessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MESSAGE);
        holder.tvtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TIME);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
        holder = (Adapter.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvmessage.setText(messagesArrayList.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.tvtime.setText(messagesArrayList.get(position).getSender()+"  "+messagesArrayList.get(position).getSentAt());
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `m.equals("89")` instead if `m == "89"`
So Your code should be like:

```
if (m.equals("89")) {
        //Returning self
        return SELF;
    }
    else{
        return OTHER;
    }
```